# JQM IOS: using setInterval() changePage() no longer works after update to JQM 1.3.1

Tags: jquery-mobile, ios6, jquery-1.9

We create distributed iPod Touch apps that work on a local classroom network.  One of our apps has a controller that allows a classroom full of students to icons around on a shared display at the front of the room.

The controller uses setInterval() to move the icon repeatedly if the student holds down their finger.  If the icon hits an object on the class display the server sends a message to the app to change to another page.  All of this was working JQM 1.0.2 until our iPods were updated.  We did a major update of PhoneGap, JQ JQM. IOS 6.1.3 and we switched to JQM 1.3.1.  We used the live() event function in the past with success.  Now we are having trouble with on().

I'll do my best to show the code here:

This part works fine:

```
// Handles controller direction events to move icon on shared display
$(document).on('vmouseup vmousedown', ".controller", function(event){
    var evType, direction;
    evType = event.type;
    event.preventDefault();
    direction = $(this).attr("data");

    if (repeater != 0){clearInterval(repeater)};
    repeater = 0;
    if(evType == 'vmousedown'){
        move(direction);
        repeater = setInterval(function(){move(direction)},200);
    } else {
        clearInterval(repeater);
        repeater = 0;
    }
});
```

This part freezes the capture page (that has the controller) on the IOS device (works fine in Safari browser on OSX).  We want to changePage("#operate"):

```
    // Handles message from the server that an object was captured
    function handleOperations(fields) {
        var tag = fields.tag;
        var message = fields.content.value;
        switch (tag) {
            case 'collective' :
                expression = message;
                $(".group-expression").html(expression);
                break;
            case 'capture' :
                term = message;
                $(".captured-expression").html(message);
                $.mobile.changePage("#operate");
                break;
        case 'flags' :
                updateOps(message);
        break;
        }
    }
```

Each of these cases involves interrupting something that is going on.  We used live() in the past for this sort of thing which happens a lot in our work.  The  server will often interrupt what the client is doing.  How do we get the live() functionality back?

Update:

If insert an alert() just before the changePage() it works. Would appreciate any thoughts. Pretty confused right now.  We can't have alerts constantly popping up.

Comment: do you get any error in console log?

Comment: Thanks Omar.  No errors when running browser.  Is there a way to see the console log for the device.  We are researchers not professional developers.

Comment: UPdate:  There are errors that have been occurring for a while from a non implemented phone gap plugin:             file:///Users/tobin/altme/worlds/sutherzone/files/UC%20Davis/UCD%20Projects/Classroom%20Networks/Development/iOS%20Development/Terms%20and%20Ops%20iOS/Terms%20and%20Operations%20iOSv4/www/cordova_plugins.jsonFailed to load resource: The requested URL was not found on this server.
file:///!gap_exec?1368036170513Failed to load resource: The requested URL was not found on this server.

Comment: I have the problem fixed.  Seems that callback functions and alerts can be a problem in IOS 6.  I enclose callbacks from the server with a setTimeout(function(){...},0) and everything now works.

Comment: switch (tag) {
            case 'collective' :
                expression = message;
                $(".group-expression").html(expression);
                break;
            case 'capture' :
                term = message;
                $(".captured-expression").html(message);
                $.mobile.changePage("#operate");
                break;
            case 'flags' :
                updateOps(message);
        break;
        }

Answer (score 1):

Fixed the problem using setTimeout()  Here's the code.

```
setTimeout(function() {
    switch (tag) {
        case 'collective' :
            expression = message;
            $(".group-expression").html(expression);
            break;
        case 'capture' :
            term = message;
            $(".captured-expression").html(message);
            $.mobile.changePage("#operate");
            break;
        case 'flags' :
            updateOps(message);
    break;
    }
}, 0);
```